# sending variable values to URL php page

Tags: php, url

I am using school's server and they apparently don't allow students to use mail() php function or anything else :( 
So I decided to use my friend's server and send data to his server.
So I have variables ready to go:

```
$to = "$to";
$subject = "$subject";
$message = "$message"; 
$headers = "$headers";
```

how do I send this data to his server where it will execute 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
He told me to call a php page on my machine that just displays the 5 pieces of info without using my session.

Comment: You might want to see how to use `curl`, `file_get_contents()` now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass it to his script using `GET`?

```
$url = "hisScript.php?";
$url .= "to=" . urlencode($to);
$url .= "&subject=" . urlencode($subject);
$url .= "&message=" . urlencode($message);
$url .= "&headers=" . urlencode($headers);

echo $url;
```

Comment: nice, where is his script located? I want to use it to send mails too :)

Comment: Hopefully he uses `HTTP_REFERER` to check where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can transmit the information either on the URL (GET) or by "submitting" the data (POST).